# Visio 2010 Organization chart

Tags: charts, microsoft-visio, hyperlink

I'm looking to build an org chart in Visio 2010 by using data from excel. There are many tutorials about this, so this part is pretty easy.
My question is, is there a way to create automatic hyperlinks for each shape that would link to the box with additional employee data ?
Like in the main box I want to have a name and title, but when you click on the box - it takes you to a standalone page with such information as education, age, email etc.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "standalone page"?

Comment: I mean additional page within the same visio file (tabs at the bottom). We want to click on the user and see more information about him/her. Preferably with ability to print.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do this. Note there are others! Mine doesn't involve any VBA.

You need a column on your spreadsheet for the name of the additional information shape with the Employee details. Employee ID or similar with a company prefix is fine.

You then create the shapes for additional details, using a stencil that automatically renames the shape name to be the Employee ID (which you will have linked to one of the Shape Data fields).

Then, edit the employee template on the org chart to include a hyperlink. Create a hyperlink to any old shape. Once that is done, substitute the name of the shape that you pointed to in the wizard with the shape data field reference with the Employee ID as a variable.

When you then map the org chart shape to a data field, the hyperlink will then go to the shape called "Employee1234".

You're basically mapping 2 shapes to your one Excel spreadsheet row, and then using one to name the shape and one that has a hyperlink that goes to shape that you just named. Ensure you edit the stencils as the starting point and although they won't work as stencils, they will work as real shapes.

If you like I can create a document with a sample?